# Link in div repeats the function on roll over

Tags: javascript

So I have a side menu made of `div`s containing some text and a link.

When I roll over the `div` I fade in an image.

When I roll over the a tag link in that `div` it repeats that same function and creates another fade in of the same image witch looks real buggy.

How can I prevent the link a tag to repeat the function

I tried to create a variable set to true on roll over the link and a if inside the fade in method but with no success?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

---

```
  $j=jQuery.noConflict();

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
              var num = 0;
              var numtot = 4;
              var delai = null;
              var stop_x=0;
              var numCur=0;
              var thisIs = 0;
              var delayRoll = 0;
              var count = null;
              var overlink = false;

//on ini

//--//           




 $j(document).ready(function() {


          function start() {
              delai=setInterval(test, 5000);
              console.log(">> start interval");//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>trace;


          };


          numtot = ($j("#news dl dt").size())-1;

          test();
           start();
                             })





            function fistImage(){


                //if(delayRoll==0){

            $j("#news dl dd").fadeOut();
            $j("#news dl dt").removeClass('current');

            console.log("num on test: " + num);//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>trace;
            console.log("numCur on test: " + numCur);//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>trace;

            //console.log("current is"+ );//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>trace;

            $j("#news dl dt").eq(num).addClass('current');      
            $j("#news dl dt").eq(num).next('dd').fadeIn(500);
            if (num>=numtot) {num = 0;} else {num ++;}; 


                //}
            }

            //firstImage();

              //--//



              ////////--------//////// NEXT IMAGE METHOD
              function nextImage(){

                  if( overlink == false || overlink == true){


console.log("delayRoll image: " + delayRoll);//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>trace;
$j("#news dl dd").fadeOut();
$j("#news dl dt").removeClass('current');
$j(thisIs).addClass('current');
$j(thisIs).next('dd').fadeIn(500);  
//stop_x=1;

var new_pos=$j(thisIs).attr('id').substring(4, 5);
              new_pos=parseInt(new_pos);

          if (numtot==new_pos) {new_pos = 0;} 
              num = new_pos;
          numtot = ($j("#news dl dt").size())-1;

                  }


  }
  //--//


   function test() {
          //console.log("num on test: " + num);//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>trace;


  if(stop_x==0){
      fistImage();

  }


  if(stop_x==1){




  }};

  //--//
      //--/

      delai=setInterval(test, 5000);

  //--//



    //-- OVERLAY//
  $j(".overlay").mouseover(function() {
                  stop_x=1;

              }).mouseout( function (){

              stop_x=0;

          });




  //--//mouseover
  $j("#news dl dt").mouseover(function() {
                thisIs = $j(this);
                stop_x=1;                      
                 clearInterval(delai);
                 nextImage();
                 delayRoll==2;

                                       })



   $j("#news dl dt").mouseout(function() {
                            stop_x==0;
                            firstImage();
                            delayRoll=0;            
                                        })




  $("#news dl dt a").live("mouseover mouseout", function() {
// alert(this.href); 
  //return false;
  overlink=true;
});








                                  })//close duc ready
  //--//
```

---

and here the html

```
<div id="news" class="slideshow">
          <dl>


              <dt id="pos_1">08/16/11<br /><br />Holy Cross to Welcome Class of 2015 on Aug. 27<br />
      <a class="more" href="blog/2011/08/16/holy-cross-to-welcome-class-of-2015-on-aug-27/index.html">See more &gt;</a>
      </dt>
      <dd>
  <div class="overlay">
  <p>Holy Cross to Welcome Class of 2015 on Aug. 27                     <span class="nav">
                                                                                                                                                                                                      <img src="wp-content/themes/marsten/images/ico_more_white.png" width="14" height="14" alt="" />

<div id="disLink"><span><a class="more" href="blog/2011/08/16/holy-cross-to-welcome-class-of-2015-on-aug-27/index.html" >See more &gt;</a></span></div>


      </span> 
      </p>
  <div id="boxit"><p class="author">by <a href="blog/2011/08/16/holy-cross-to-welcome-class-of-2015-on-aug-27/index.html"></a>
  <a href="blog/author/nmarkant/index.html" title="Posts by Nikolas Markantonatos">Nikolas Markantonatos</a></p></div>
      </div>
  <img alt="" src="wp-content/uploads/2011/08/gate2.jpg" width="612" height="451" />
              </dd>
```

Comment: Please provide the Javascript code you are using and enough of the HTML to see what it's operating upon.

Answer (score 0):

Trying doing a `event.stopPropagation` during the hover over after you fade in...